# Android ProgressDialog not showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

In the following code:

```
Log.v("dialog", "dialogshow");
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UBActivity.this, "", "Loading calendar, please wait...",     true);

boolean res;
try {
    res = new Utils().new DownloadCalendarTask().execute().get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.v("downloadcalendar", "interruptedexecution : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    res = false;
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    Log.v("downloadcalendar", "executionexception : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    res = false;
}
Log.v("dialog", "dialogdismiss");
dialog.dismiss();
```

According to logcat there is an 8 second difference between dialogshow and dialogdismiss showing in the log, yet I don't see the ProgressDialog appear at all. The background action is happening not in the UI thread (it's an AsyncTask) so that shouldn't be the problem?

Many thanks!u

Comment: What does the code of your AsyncTask<> look like?  Are you doing a lot of work in `onPreExecute`?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your ProgressDialog inside your AsyncTask:
Create the ProgressDialog and show it in PreExecute.
Do your downloading in the Background and dismiss the ProgressDialog in PostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

In AsyncTask There Are Three Method....

**OnpreExecute** you start your progressDialog and then Your task is running in **do in  background**..
After completing the **do in background** Methods the **onPostExecute** method is calling itself and then Dismiss your dialog onPostExecute method....

Comment: Nice copy/paste from my answer :D hehe, just kidding :)

Comment: Nope i never copy paste i know very well Asynctask and how it works........... and when i attend my answer You answer first and i dont show you answered and i also add aasync task in my app there were download images from internet in Background,,,,,,,,,Most of Java,.Net technology is used this fundamental for Background Process,,,OK..........

Comment: Chill dude... I'm sure you know it. But I just posted my answer, and 5 min after you gave him an almost identical answer. Not that it matters, thats why I added a smiley and the "hehe". 
Didn't mean to ruin your day.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the `ProgressDialog`, I think it is because of the `Context`.

Are you sure `UBActivity.this` is the right `Activity`?

I had the exact same problem and fixed it by passing the `Context` to my ASync class constructor.